# How to run linux VM hosted by hyper-v which runs docker

Tags: windows, centos, hyper-v, docker, windows-server-2016

I have a Server 2016 hyper-v host
I want to run a centos VM on that host that has docker installed on it

Is this possible? Do I need to enable nested virtualization somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure on the Centos VM side - you do not need to enable it, but at hte moment you need to run a decently modern Intel processor (not AMD) as only that one supports nested virtualization.

It sounds convoluted, though. You would be better off running a Hyper-V Container on the windows server with one of the linux images https://blog.docker.com/2016/10/considerations-running-docker-windows-server-2016-hyper-v-vms/

Comment: Im confused "You would be better off running a Hyper-V Container on the windows server with one of the linux images"- isn't this the same thing? by "one of the linux images" do you mean like a prebuild linux vm for running docker?

Comment: Reading that doc they say this is possible: "You can run a Hyper-V VM with a Linux OS on a physical host running Windows Server.  Inside the VM, you can run containers built with Linux"- are there any docker docs or examples of how to do this I could not find any guidance on their website

Comment: @red888 No, it is like a docker image that contains the linux kernel. You manage the contains as CONTAINER and the Hyper-V instance is transparent (and needed to run a second kernel). Easier to maintain (as the "kernel" is a docker image). Check https://serverfault.com/questions/807609/hyper-v-containers-are-going-to-allow-running-of-linux-containers

Answer (score 0):

Little late to but you need to expose virtualization extensions.

`Set-VMProcessor <VMName> -ExposeVirtualizationExtensions $true`

Do that when the machine is off and make sure you have an intel cpu.

[Source](https://www.altaro.com/hyper-v/enable-nested-virtualization/)